# How could I swap rows in a 2D array defined using pointers to array?

Tags: c, arrays, swap, pointer-to-array

I want to swap two rows of a 2d array defined as bellow.

```
    double (*mat)[N];
    mat = (double(*)[N])malloc(m*sizeof(double [N]));
    ...
    swap(mat, mat+1);
```

But my `swap(mat, mat+1);` only swaps the first element in each row.

```
void swap(double **a,double **b){
    double *temp;
    temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}
```

The same swap works if I use it one a 2D array defined `double **mat;` with dinamically allocated lines and rows.

Comment: Don't use double pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct -- you must pass *pointer-to-pointer* to `int` as the parameters to your swap function. Why? You want to change the pointers themselves. Passing a simple pointer, the function would receive a copy and any changes would be lost on return.

The key here is you cannot swap rows in your allocated collection directly without using `memcpy` to actually swap the data. Why? the rows are contained within a sequential block of memory you just allocated. You can simply declare an *array-of-pointers* to the beginning of each row in your allocated collection of data and then swap pointers within the *array-of-pointers*, e.g.

```
#define MAXI 10
...

    int (*a)[MAXI] = calloc (MAXI, sizeof *a),      /* pointer to array  */
        *p[MAXI];                                   /* array of pointers */

    for (int i = 0; i < MAXI; i++) {                /* loop */
        *a[i] = i, a[i][MAXI-1] = i;                /* set first/last each row */
        p[i] = a[i];                                /* set pointer to each row */
    }
```

Now you can swap the pointers with a function taking parameters of *pointer-to-pointer*, e.g.

```
void swpptr (int **a, int **b)                      /* swap pointers */
{
    void *tmp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = tmp;
}
```

with, e.g.:

```
    puts ("\nswapping every other row...");
    for (int i = 1; i < MAXI; i+=2)                 /* loop */
        swpptr (&p[i-1], &p[i]);                    /* swap every other row */
```

A short example would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXI 10

void swpptr (int **a, int **b)                      /* swap pointers */
{
    void *tmp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = tmp;
}

void prn_ptr2ptr (int **p, int n)                   /* print n int per-pointer */
{
    for (int i = 0; i < MAXI; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            printf (" %d", p[i][j]);
        putchar ('\n');
    }
}

int main (void) {

    int (*a)[MAXI] = calloc (MAXI, sizeof *a),      /* pointer to array  */
        *p[MAXI];                                   /* array of pointers */

    for (int i = 0; i < MAXI; i++) {                /* loop */
        *a[i] = i, a[i][MAXI-1] = i;                /* set first/last each row */
        p[i] = a[i];                                /* set pointer to each row */
    }

    puts ("pre-swap:");                             /* ouput pre-swap pointers */
    prn_ptr2ptr (p, MAXI);

    puts ("\nswapping every other row...");
    for (int i = 1; i < MAXI; i+=2)                 /* loop */
        swpptr (&p[i-1], &p[i]);                    /* swap every other row */

    puts ("\npost-swap:");                          /* output post-swap pointers */
    prn_ptr2ptr (p, MAXI);
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/ptr2arrayswap
pre-swap:
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2
 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3
 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 4
 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 5
 6 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 6
 7 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 7
 8 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 8
 9 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 9

swapping every other row...

post-swap:
 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3
 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2
 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 5
 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 4
 7 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 7
 6 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 6
 9 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 9
 8 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 8
```

Look things over and let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
void swap(double **a,double **b)
```

It works because, in this case, you swap the pointer. But when you declare:

```
double (*mat)[N];
```

It is a pointer to array. it's reason why it just swaps the first value of each row.

If you want to swap two arrays, just use pointer (do not use double pointer):

```
void swap( double *m1, double *m2, size_t n )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        double tmp = m1[i];
        m1[i] = m2[i];
        m2[i] = tmp;
    }
}
```

Then when you want to swap two rows:

```
swap(mat[0], mat[1], N);
```